# tdxSpreadSheet, How can I format float numbers like '123.450' in a cell that is created in code

Tags: delphi, spreadsheet

I'm using the tdxSpreadSheet component.

I have a customer that requires 3 decimals in a spreadsheet column like '123.450' but the spreadsheet always formats as '123.45' and that's not good for the customer.

I can not find anything in the documentation or in any example I found.

I know it's possible to change the format using excel after this computer-created spreadsheet have been saved as a file. But as this is a report that always changes so the customer wants it generated 'correctly'.

Anyone who has an idea how I can fix this?

here's a code sample...

```
  with ssStock.ActiveSheetAsTable.CreateCell(ARow, ACol) do
  begin
    try
      if (AA = 'INVOICE NO') or (AA = 'ACT LENGTH') or (AA = 'NOM LENGTH') or (AA = 'PCS') then
        AsInteger := strToInt(AText)
      else if (AA = 'PORT OF DESTINATION') or (AA = 'CONTAINER NO') or (AA = 'ETD') or (AA = 'ETA') or (AA = 'PRODUCT') or (AA = 'QUALITY') or
           (AA = 'SHIPPER') or (AA =  'BOOK NO') or (AA = 'VESSEL') or (AA = 'Reference') then
        AsString := AText
      else if (AA = 'ACT M3') or (AA = 'PRICE VOLUME') or (AA = 'PRICE')  then begin

        SetText(AText);//AsFloat := strToFloat(AText)
      end
      else begin
        free;
        exit;
      end;
      Style.Font.Style := [];
    finally
    end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Not sure if this works with `SetText` or if you need to use `AsFloat` after all.

```
with ssStock.ActiveSheetAsTable.CreateCell(ARow, ACol) do
begin
  Style.DataFormat.FormatCode := '0.000';
end;
```

[According to their forum](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T133925/with-dxspreadsheet-how-to-set-a-cell-number-format-programmatically) (which is also inspiration for the snippet above), this topic was under-documented, but that was 6 years ago, so maybe they fixed it by now.

Comment: You made my day... A quick and perfect answer.

Comment: @larand There are certain ways of expressing gratitude for helpful and correct answers, outlined in: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)